# How can I get only filled rows with spreadsheets.get, given a sheet ID but not a sheet title?

Tags: google-sheets-api

Google Sheets API v4 has two methods for getting spreadsheet data:

- `spreadsheets.get`, i.e. `GET https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}`
- `spreadsheets.get.values`, i.e. `GET https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}/values/{range}`

The `range` path param of the latter lets you specify a sheet title (without any cell range in A1 notation), which automagically returns only filled rows of that sheet. The former has a `range` query param which does the same; *however*...

I don't want to use the title of a sheet, since titles are mutable. I want to use only the ID of a sheet, since IDs are immutable.

With `spreadsheets.get`, I can indeed find the sheet I want, using only ID, in the retrieved object's `sheets` array. However, by not specifying a `range` query param, I've retrieved every single row of the spreadsheet.

So, how can I get all filled rows and no empty rows of a sheet in a spreadsheet, given only the spreadsheet ID and sheet ID?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use sheet ID in Google Sheets API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52934537/how-to-use-sheet-id-in-google-sheets-api)

Answer (score 2):

By following the example from [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/reading), you can use the  `spreadsheetid` to indicate where you would provide the **spreadsheet ID** which can be discovered from the spreadsheet URL.
You can read a single range by following the `spreadsheet.values.get` request that reads the value stored in the range.
For example:

```
GET https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/spreadsheetId/values/Sheet1!A1:D5
```

**Note:** Empty trailing rows and columns are omitted.

Comment: Hello, I'm looking to get a range using both the ID of the spreadsheet *and* the ID of the sheet (i.e. the "gid" that appears at the very end of a Sheets URL). Essentially, I can't use any A1 notation. Thank you and sorry!

Comment: I had to select complete sheet and do Formatting -> Clear Formatting. It was sending many blank rows which apparently had some formatting.